# Merge second text box input text value as new line in existing created image

Tags: javascript, php, image

Working stencils text project i have created code to convert input text to image it's working good but i have multiple text box (e.g) Text box1, Text box2,Text box3.The problem is that if i type in text box 1 its convert text to image and after if i type text into text box2 or text box3 its convert the new image here i just want create that text in new line with the first image converted text from text box1.

Demo link:-[Click Here](http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/stackdemo/)

Bellow example snap shot.here you can see that first text box crate line 1 and second text box create image on second or new line on one image.

[image: different line]

**Bellow is my code index.php**

```
<?php ?>

 <html>
 <body>

 <img class="stencil-main" id="stencil-main" />
<span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">Enter Text-</span><input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;"
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('stencil-main').src='some.php?img='+this.value" />

        <br> 
        <img class="stencil-mains" id="stencil-mains" />    
        <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">Enter Text-</span><input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;"
       onkeyup="document.getElementById('stencil-mains').src='some.php?img='+this.value" />


       </body>
       </html>
```

**2)Bellow is php code to convert text to image some.php**

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/png");
$cid=$_GET['img'];    
####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################
$imagewidth = 500;
$imageheight = 100;
$fontsize = "20";
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "ByzantineEmpire.ttf";
$text = $cid ;
$text2="sanjay";
$backgroundcolor = "FFFFFF";
$textcolor = "#000000";
######################## END USER EDITS ########################

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);

### Get exact dimensions of text string
$box = @imageTTFBbox($fontsize,$fontangle,$font,$text);

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;

### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);

### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location
imagettftext ( $im, $fontsize, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $text );

### Display completed image as PNG
$html=imagepng($im);


### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);



?>
```

Comment: Every input is requesting a new image on its own. You need to point them to the same location. Furthermore, your PHP isn't set up to handle multiple inputs. It's just one line of text. You need to do a little bit of math and some evaluation of the input values here and  there and voilà.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the values of your text fields and send them all to some.php the same time, now you are sending them individually. Also the some.php needs to get both of them and generate a single image with them. Here is how you can do it using jQuery load function:

`index.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('input[name="stencil-text"]').keyup(function(){

                var img_text = $('input[name="stencil-text"]').map(function(){
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();

                var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'some.php?img=' + img_text).load(function() {
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        alert('broken image!');
                    } else {
                        $("#stencil-main").html(img);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stencil-main"></div>
    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">Enter Text-</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;">

    <br>

    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">Enter Text-</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Here jQuery gets all the values of input fields with name "stencil-text", you can add as many input fields you want and it will work the same way. The only thing you need to do is to change the `$imageheight` otherwise the image will get cropped.

`some.php`

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$cid = str_replace(',', "\n", $_GET['img']);
####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################
$imagewidth = 500;
$imageheight = 120;
$fontsize = "20";
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "ByzantineEmpire.ttf";
$text = $cid ;
$text2="sanjay";
$backgroundcolor = "FFFFFF";
$textcolor = "#000000";
######################## END USER EDITS ########################

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);

### Get exact dimensions of text string
$box = imageTTFBbox($fontsize,$fontangle,$font,$text);

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;

### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);

### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location
imagettftext ( $im, $fontsize, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $text );

### Display completed image as PNG
$html=imagepng($im);


### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Full solution to convert text image and change the font of text line by line**

Demo Link:- [Click Here](http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/custom%20line%20font/stencile%20text%20seprate/)

**1) Create index.php with bellow code**

```
<?php

?>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('input[name="stencil-text"]').keyup(function(){

               var img_text = $('input[name="stencil-text"]').map(function(){

                   return $(this).val();
              }).get();

               var fontsize = $('input[name="stencil-text-size"]').map(function(){
                   return $(this).val();
              }).get();

                 var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'some.php?img=' + img_text+'&fontsize='+fontsize).load(function() { 
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        alert('broken image!');
                    } else {
                        //alert(fontsize);
                        $("#stencil-main").html(img);
                    }
                });     

            });  
              $('input[name="stencil-text-size"]').keyup(function(){

               var img_text = $('input[name="stencil-text"]').map(function(){

                   return $(this).val();
              }).get();

               var fontsize = $('input[name="stencil-text-size"]').map(function(){
                   return $(this).val();
              }).get();


                 var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'some.php?img=' + img_text+'&fontsize='+fontsize).load(function() { 
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        alert('broken image!');
                    } else {
                        //alert(fontsize);  
                        $("#stencil-main").html(img);
                    }
                }); 








            });    




        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

      <div id ="all">

     <div id="box" style="margin-left: 360px;">
    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">FONT SIZE LINE1 -</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text-size" value="100" style="margin-left: 15px;">



    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">LINE 1-</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;">


    <br>  

     <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">FONT SIZE LINE2 -</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text-size" value="50" style="margin-left: 15px;">

    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">LINE 2-</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;">

    <br>

      <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">FONT SIZE LINE3 -</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text-size" value="20" style="margin-left: 15px;">
    <span class="line" style="margin-left: 578px;">LINE 3-</span>
    <input type="text" name="stencil-text" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        </div>
      <div id="stencil-main" style="margin-top: -652px;margin-left:-297px"></div> 
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**2) Create some.php with bellow code**

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/png");
$myArray = explode(',', $_GET['img']);  
$fontarray = explode(',' , $_GET['fontsize']);   

####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################
$imagewidth = 1000;
$imageheight = 1000;
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "ByzantineEmpire.ttf";
$backgroundcolor = "FFFFFF";
$textcolor = "#000000";
######################## END USER EDITS ########################

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);

### Get exact dimensions of text string


### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location      
$count=count($myArray);
    $box = imageTTFBbox(50,$fontangle,$font,'test');  

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;

### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
        $newcount=count($fontarray); 

        for($j=0;$j<$newcount;$j++)

{

    if($j==$i)
    {
     $xcord=$xcord+2;
   $ycord=$ycord+100;
    imagettftext ( $im, $fontarray[$j], $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $myArray[$i] );

}

 } 

}

$html=imagepng($im);

### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);   

?>
```

**You will get like bellow snap shot sample out put after run the code**

[image: out put]